# Visual Studio code - convert spaces to tab and then save in spaces again

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-code

I'm coding in a language that has an official formatting tool that uses 2 spaces. While I think using the agreed standard is good, it's really straining to read the code. Is there a way to automagically display it as 8 spaces, or convert to 8 spaces/2tabs when loading the file and then save it to 2-spaces again afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *find and replace* (CTRL + H). In **find** field you type 4 spaces, and in **replace with** field type one tab; then press **replace all**.

[image]

Or you can use some online code beautifier script and it will work.

Comment: Tab can't be entered into that field, it just navigates away

Comment: P47 R1ck's answer is on the right track, it's just missing a piece. Ben Alan is right, you can't just type "tab" into the box. What you *can* do is type tab anywhere in the application, copy/cut it, and paste it into the "Replace" box. Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Regarding "type one tab". Pressing the TAB key will just leave the replacement value text field. Instead, the TAB character must be pasted into the replace text field. The quickest way I found to "copy" a TAB character without leaving VS code is to temporarily turn on Tabs for indentation, type a TAB, copy it, and then return to Spaces for indentation. This is all done via the "Spaces: 2" item in the bar at the bottom of the window. Clicking on it will enable the option to flip to TABs.

Comment: Hit the regex button and use `\t`.

Comment: @Gabe and @ chaotic3quilibrium, at least one of you, could please move your comment into an answer so that we can recommend something useful? While @ Brad 's answer is useful for more advanced users, personally, I would be more safe just copy-pasting a tab and don't bother with the regex state (enabled/disabled)